# Remover borda tracejada quando se clica em um select combo

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Não consigo remover a borda tracejada que surge quando se clica em um item de um combo box, já tentei o recurso outline:none do css3, porém não funcionou. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia por gentileza postar o código HTML e CSS da página?

Comment: Na realidade não tenho código desenvolvido, mas é um simples select. Este componente no mozilla por padrão possui uma borda tracejada quando sofre o clique do mouse e eu queria remove-la

Comment: Tem como colocar um print ao menos?

Comment: Claro! Já inseri

Comment: Coitada da borda tracejada, ta fazendo nada de mais...

Comment: também acho! Mas sabe como é, a solicitação vem de cima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A janela suspensa com as opções é parte do que é chamado de [ShadowDOM](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/). Nas especificações CSS atuais, nível 3, não há nenhuma maneira para atingir a maioria dos elementos ShadowDOM. Você pode ler as especificações sobre o ShadowDOM [aqui](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/), embora não há muito lá sobre o que você quer.

Mas, existem opções como [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) que redesenha todo o combobox usando Javascript.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056300/select-menu-option-border-none

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, mas a ideia não é reformular todo o componente, só mesmo remover a borda.

Comment: Remover a borda infelizmente não da, os browsers não suportam ainda. 
O bom do Select2 é que ele deixa seu combobox "bonitinho" sem voce precisa mexer no seu html, apenas instanciando o metodo js... vale tentar.

Comment: Valeu pela dica!